# Matlab - Calling one method from another method matlab

Tags: matlab, oop, methods

Two classes:

```
classdef first < handle
    methods
        function hello(obj)
            disp('hello ok')
            obj_second.bye
        end
    end
end
```

and

```
classdef second < handle
    methods
        function bye(obj)
            disp('bye ok')
        end
    end
end
```

I'd like to be able to call obj_second.bye from obj_first.

---

```
>> obj_first=first;
>> obj_second=second;
>> obj_first.hello
hello ok
Undefined variable "obj_second" or class "obj_second.bye".

Error in first/hello (line 5)
            obj_second.bye

>>
```

obj_second seems to have to be constructed in the class "first" to be considered by this class; what do you think?

Comment: You probably need parens after `bye`: `obj_second.bye()`, instead of `obj_second.bye`.

Comment: Also, you have to post what your actual problem is. What have you tried running and how did the result differ from your expectation?

Comment: Where should the pointer to `obj_second` come from, you never initialize it? Please describe the behaviour you want to implement.

Comment: @Daniel Please see my modified question.

Answer (score 1):

Within your `hello` method, you only have access to the local variable `obj` representing the current instance of **first** class calling it (e.g. `obj_first` here) and potentially the `properties` of the class. But you can't access other extern variables like `obj_second`.

To do so, you will have to pass it as parameter:

```
classdef first < handle
    methods
        function hello(obj, obj2)
            disp('hello ok')
            obj2.bye()
        end
    end
end
```

and

```
>> obj_first.hello(obj_second)
```